# Change color of HTML Page via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML + JavaScript Code for Changing background color of HTML Page from JS based on the color option chosen. However irrespective of any label I choose, my background is turning red only on mouseover and white on mouseout. Rest of the color changes are not happening. Where am I going wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Color Highlighter
    </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(target)
    {
         document.body.style.background = target;
    }

    function restoreColor()
    {
         document.body.style.background ="white";
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <label onmouseover="changeColor('red');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Red<br>
    <label onmouseover="changeColor('blue');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Blue<br>
    <label onmouseover="changeColor('yellow');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Yellow<br>
    <label onmouseover="changeColor('green');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Green<br>
</body>
```

Comment: You neglected to close your `label` elements properly …

Answer (score 4):

Your code is almost fine.

> You **forgot to complete** `</label>` tag dude.

```
<label onmouseover="changeColor('red');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Red</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('blue');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Blue</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('yellow');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Yellow</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('green');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Green</label><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close each <label> tag with </label>:

```
<label onmouseover="changeColor('red');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Red</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('blue');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Blue</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('yellow');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Yellow</label><br>
<label onmouseover="changeColor('green');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Green</label><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your HTML is invalid. You haven't closed your labels, so the first label *contains* all subsequent labels, and thus swallows the mouseover and mouseout events, preventing them from hitting the other labels.

Here's a demo of the problem, and how it can be solved:

### HTML

```
<!-- fixed markup -->
<label class="valid" onmouseover="changeColor('red');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Red</label>
<label class="valid" onmouseover="changeColor('blue');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Blue</label>
<label class="valid" onmouseover="changeColor('yellow');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Yellow</label>
<label class="valid" onmouseover="changeColor('green');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Green</label>
<br/>
<br/>

<!-- original invalid markup -->
<label class="invalid" onmouseover="changeColor('red');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Red<br>
<label class="invalid" onmouseover="changeColor('blue');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Blue<br>
<label class="invalid" onmouseover="changeColor('yellow');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Yellow<br>
<label class="invalid" onmouseover="changeColor('green');" onmouseout="restoreColor();">Green<br>
```

### CSS

```
.valid {
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.invalid {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
window.changeColor = function(target)
{
    document.body.style.background = target;
}

window.restoreColor = function()
{
    document.body.style.background ="white";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ufgg0uw/2/

[image: demo]

Using CSS, I've bordered the invalid labels with red and the valid labels with blue, so you can see the difference in behavior. It shows clearly how the first invalid label swallows up all following labels.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `changeColor('white')` for onmouseout?

Comment: Since i have to change to white only onmouseout, how does it change anything to make function parameterized or not?

Comment: You know the changeColor function works - if you just use that method instead of creating a new one, it'll probably work. (I'm recommending you just use one function instead of two)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your markup.  Why do none of the label tags close?  The behavior of JavaScript event propagation up through a target element's ancestor nodes would cause the behavior you describe.